# In Ruby is "name" a reserved property and if so how do I use :name attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

disclaimer and I'm ruby/rails n00b.

I have a simple ActiveRecord class:

```
class LandingPage < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :parent_id, :published
end
```

Now, I haven't worked out the pattern yet, but sometime object.name return the right value, other time object.name or, inside the class, self.name return a value like this:

> <LandingPage:0x007fd05c605980>

I'm guessing it's because "name" is like a reserved property? But sometimes it works. Can I use "name" as a property or not?

Comment: you can definately use 'name' as an attribute name. Your problem seems to be different. please provide some more info on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're inside a class method

```
class Foo
  def self.foo
    puts self.name
  end
end
```

`Foo.foo` will return the class name which is Foo.  however, given the following

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :name

  def self.foo
    puts self.name
  end

  def method1
    puts self.name
  end
end
```

`Foo.new(name: 'my name').method1` will return `my name`

Answer (score 2):

Name is not a reserved property in Ruby and not in Ruby on Rails. I think you're printing out the return value of the `to_s` method.

If you're using the poor man's debugger (`Kernel#puts` or `Kernel#p`) then it will use the `to_s` method.

Try:

```
puts landing_page.name
```

instead of `puts landing_page`. Or if you're using it in a view, it's the same:

```
<%= @landing_page.name %>
```

instead of `<%= @landing_page %>`.

Comment: +1 thanks Karaszi! you're totally right. I gave the answer to jvnill as it more directly answers the question, however you're 100% correct.